# How to get the domain value for a cookie in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, dns

Using JavaScript I'd like to get the `domain` value for a specific cookie.

Is this possible? If so, how?

To clarify: I'm not looking for the *value* of the cookie. I'm on `subdomain.example.com` and I need to remove a cookie whose name is known but its domain value is something like `.example.com`. In short: I'd like to get the value of `.example.com`.

Comment: The only way I know of to get cookie attributes (path, domain, expiry, security) is to tack them on the value when you create or modify the cookie or its value.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Sorry, all you get is what you see in `document.cookie`. The cookie metadata like `path`, `domain` and `expires` are not visible to site code (neither to JavaScript nor to the server-side).

To read a cookie that is being shadowed by a cookie with a more-specific `domain` or `path`, the only thing you can do is load a page for which the more-specific cookie is out-of-scope, and read it from there.

If, as you say, you only need to *remove* a cookie, what you could do is try to remove the cookie at every possible level of specificity, eg.:

```
    document.cookie= 'foo=;domain=sub.domain.example.com;expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT';
    document.cookie= 'foo=;domain=domain.example.com;expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT';
    document.cookie= 'foo=;domain=example.com;expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT';
```

and similarly with the `path` variable. You could put this in a nested loop for each path and domain part, splitting on `.` for the domain and `/` for the path.

Comment: So basically you recommend carpet bombing. I can't see another solution either. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way of describing it!

Comment: How does the Firefox Web Developer "View Cookie Information" utility do it? Apparently, the domain information is in there somewhere.

Comment: @Gregory: The Web Developer extension runs as chrome, so has a higher level of access to Firefox's internal objects than you can get from plain old web site JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

You can only access cookies from the same domain (this includes subdomains).  Obviously doing otherwise would be a security concern.

Comment: I think that's not quite true.  subdomains can set cookies for a *. parent domain, as I understand it: https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

Comment: Correct: one of the things cookies can do that localStorage cannot: you can set it on the main domain.  Programmatically figuring out what the "toplevel" domain that you can set it on is can be complex though: you can set a cookie on amazon.com but not co.uk as co it's a special SLD. You'd have to set it on amazon.co.uk instead. So it's not as simple as "just the last two segments."