# Setting a cookie twice?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, cookies

I have a scenario where a cookie(named "TSTMSG") gets set on user login.
Then it checks for the cookie existance and displays the alert.

The alert needs to get displayed on all the pages except homepage and once its displayed it should never come again until the cookie gets expired.
I am not able to to understand how make a check that the alert should not come again.

I have tried setting a flag in the cookie and updating it once the user gets the alert. But it resulted in duplicate cookie creation.
Please help.

Comment: You could set two cookies, one for the login and one for the alert.
When the alert is displayed delete the alert cookie. It should not show again. Or a session (in php $_SESSION).

Comment: Thanks for that. Can there be a logic where I can make use of single cookie only.

Comment: if you want one cookie take a look here for the duplication problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621775/cookie-is-set-twice-how-to-remove-the-duplicate