# How should HTTP Cookie be decoded?

Tags: http

If I send this header to the server:

```
Cookie: spaces=foo+bar%20baz; repeat=foo; repeat=bar
```

How should it be decoded?

---

PHP decodes it as

```
array (
    'spaces' => 'foo bar baz',
    'repeat' => 'foo',
)
```

But I think it should be

```
array(
    'spaces' => 'foo bar baz',
    'repeat' => array('foo','bar'),
)
```

Which is correct?

Comment: Why are you trying to handle duplicate cookies? I'm surprised browsers even send those.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Because I encountered a very hard to track bug exactly because of this in the past. Certain versions of IE will send them if you set the cookie more than once with a different domain or path, but they both match. I'm implementing PSR7 right now; if I can solve this problem in there, I might as well.

Comment: It's basically [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5621775/65387) that I'm trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the known habit/peculiarity of overwriting any external parameters (GET/POST/COOKIE), when a parameter name occurs more than once.

For example with a query string such as `?spaces=foo+bar%20baz&repeat=foo&repeat=bar`, you would have the same problem – in `$_GET['repeat']`, only the value `bar` would “survive”. (That should be the same in your cookie example btw., it should be `'repeat' => 'bar'`, not `'repeat' => 'foo'`.)

To avoid this, square brackets at the end of the parameter name have to be used. Try

```
Cookie: spaces=foo+bar%20baz; repeat[]=foo; repeat[]=bar
```

– that should get you the array structure that you want in `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Well I did test it. PHP returns `'repeat' => 'foo'` in `$_COOKIE` when I test with cURL using `-H 'Cookie: spaces=foo+bar; repeat=foo; repeat=bar'`.

Comment: I'm not concerned about avoiding the problem; I'm parsing the headers myself. I want to know what the correct behaviour is so that I don't make the same mistake. If the `$_GET` behaviour is wrong too, then I should parse that manually as well.

Comment: Why would you want to parse it yourself? And it would not only be `$_COOKIE` and `$_GET`, but `$_POST` as well (as I said, this behavior is consistent in PHP whenever external parameters are considered – it has to do with the old way of creating global variables out of them automatically, and therefor assigning `$foo` from a parameter named `foo` twice would simply overwrite that variable) – and when it comes to parsing _that_ correctly, you are going to have a lot of fun, considering stuff such a `multipart/form-data` requests etc. …

Comment: See my comment under the question for an explanation. I might just handle cookies because it's pretty easy, and that's the only one that's caused a bug for me.