# Duplicate key is getting set in Javascript Cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, duplicates

My issue is that the JS cookie gets set with two "viewmore" keys. Here "viewmore" is set to true and false. Can anyone help diagnose please!?

```
 > document.cookie
    "viewmore=true; SESSID=fjs0fmojglrih7; viewmore=false; user=1"
```

Shouldn't the "viewmore" key be getting overwritten and not duplicated with a different value?

**Code that didn't work:**

```
document.cookie = "viewmore=false";
document.cookie = "viewmore=true";
```

**Code that worked:** needed an expiry set

```
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);

document.cookie = "viewmore=false; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
document.cookie = "viewmore=true; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
```

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621775/cookie-is-set-twice-how-to-remove-the-duplicate

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates it?

Comment: @ChristianHill Thanks that one gave me the idea to add an expiry time to the cookie, which ended up fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See above post for working code that fixed my problem.

Seems like it should be considered a good habit to set an expiry with cookies.