# How to avoid duplicate cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

In my application I set a cookie using jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1 (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) like this:

```
$.removeCookie("Test_Cookie");
$.cookie("Test_Cookie", "xxx");
```

I want this cookie to only exist once but under some circumstances the cookie exists twice.

How is that possible and what is the best practice to make sure a certain cookie exists only once?

Comment: what do you mean, "exist twice"? you have two `Test_Cookie` cookies show up in the user's cookie jar?

Comment: Yes. See screenshot from Fiddler: http://imgur.com/WlYu987

Comment: check the raw headers and see what the `set-cookie` is. if you have two cookies but with different paths, you can get the same name/value, and which of those your browser returns is undefined/variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621775/cookie-is-set-twice-how-to-remove-the-duplicate

Comment: So, if I understand you right, two cookies with the same name are only possible if they have different paths? So I should define the path as well to avoid it? Like this: $.removeCookie("Test_Cookie", { path: '/' }); $.cookie("Test_Cookie", "xxx", { path: '/' });

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.prototype.split()` to convert `document.cookie` to an array of key value strings (`key=value`), then you can iterate over these, split them, and if the key is the value, break. Please see below for an example:

```
function checkCookieExists( cookieName ){
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'); //returns lots of these: key=value
  var toCheckCookie = cookieName; //checks if this cookie exists

  cookies.forEach(function( cookie ){ //foreach cookie
    var key = cookie.split('=')[0]; //the key cookie

    if (key.toLowerCase() === toCheckCookie) //if the current key is the toCheckCookie
    {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way to get duplicate cookies is to have a page at company.com and another page at dev.company.com. Then requests to dev.company.com will get cookies for domains .company.com and .dev.company.com. The HTTP responses from dev.company.com can never change the cookies the browser is storing for company.com. This means you cannot "clear" all the duplicate cookies with HTTP response from dev.

This can be frustrating because often the library to handle cookies will only return a single cookie for a key. A valid HTTP cookie header is "Cookie: zyx=data1; zyx=data2" Then your library will return only one of these, likely the first one.

A common solution for this is to use a different cookie key for different domains: "Cookie: dev.company.com-xyz=data1; company.com-xyz=data2"

Another solution is to get the HTTP Cookie header, parse it while handling multiple cookies and use the first one that is valid. Like with a valid auth or a valid JWT.